# Salvaging TMP36

Tags: sensor, components

Looking to scavenge a tmp36 off of some fried electronics, would anybody have any leads on where to look for this type of sensor. I normally wouldn't mind to buy one, but I live in a pretty remote part of the world and don't really want to order one in. Recommendations for any Arduino compatible sensor would be good as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are remote you can use a diode as a temperature sensor. ~2mV/C, you'd have to calibrate it yourself.  Drive it with a current source ~10uA and read the voltage.  I guess you might want a bit of gain to get the voltage up to what the aruino wants.  (Does it have a low voltage ADC?)

Comment: The arduino apparently reads everything in 5V'ish, but some articles that I have read point to deviations in what this number actually is, notably: 

http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/making-accurate-adc-readings-on-arduino

I'm a bit of a noobie when it comes to this stuff, but looking to do a project with temperature sensors and set up a database to record them in.

Comment: OK If you know about opamps and gain, then the diode would be OK.  Otherwise it's perhaps best to stick with a sensor that outputs a voltage in the range of your ADC.  There are a lot of IC temperature sensors.. I've never used them, try searching on digikey.